# AlignParentBottom a widget in SingleChildScrollView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to align a button at bottom of a scrollable screen. For scrolling I used SingleChildScrollView and inside which I added all the widgets. Now the only issue I face is the button is not sticking at the bottom on scroll. Help would be appreciated.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the buy now button and add to cart button aligned at bottom. If we scroll the entire page, the button will not be scrollable, instead it will be sticking at bottom. I want to implement in this way.

Comment: The button is and must be inside the scroll view ? Like you scroll through your widget AND then you have the button at the end, OR you scroll through your list but at the same time you have a button at the bottom of the screen ?
Can you share some code pls ?

Comment: Please show us your code and show an image/screenshot of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Add an image with explanation of what I was looking for. please check it in the question area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an stack and put All the widgets except button as its First child and then the button as another child of stack. Below it the example code -

```
class MyNewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children:[
            Container(
              height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child:SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  // Provide Your Widget here                
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom:0,
              child:Align(
                alignment:Alignment.center,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child:Text("Button"),
                  onPressed:(){},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```